# Remove last occurence of invisible unicode character using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string `my string` , there is an invisible character \u{E0000} at the end of this string, I wanted to know how I can use regex to remove this character so that if I were to split the string using `.split(' ')`, it would say the length is 2 and not 3 which is what it is showing right now.

This is the regex I am currently using to remove the character, however when I split the string it still shows the length is 3 and not 2. The split would like look `['my', 'string']`.

`.replace(/[\u034f\u2800(\u{E0000})\u180e\ufeff\u2000-\u200d\u206D]/gu, '');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The invisible character you have there is 2 code points, so you need to replace a sequence of 2 unicode escapes: `\u{e0000}\u{dc00}`.
However, you also seem to be misunderstanding the way split works.  If you have a space at the end of the string, it will still try to split it into a separate element.  See below example where there is no special character following:

```js
// removing the special character so the length of string is 10 with my string
console.log(
  "my string ".length,
  "my string ".replace(/[\u034f\u2800(\u{e0000}\u{dc00})\u180e\ufeff\u2000-\u200d\u206D]/gu, '')
    .length
);

console.log(
  // use trim to remove trailing space so that it behaves the way you want
  "my string ".replace(/[\u034f\u2800(\u{e0000}\u{dc00})\u180e\ufeff\u2000-\u200d\u206D]/gu, '')
    .trim().split(' ')
);

// notice that it still tries to split the final into a 3rd element.
console.log( //\u0020 is the hex code for space
  ("my string" + "\u0020").split(' ')
);
```

Note that you may need to adjust your Regex.  I haven't checked, but it is highly likely that the unicode characters you are using are not correct, and do not take into account multi-codepoint characters.

I've created a function below for extracting full escape sequences.

```js
var codePoints = (char, pos, end) => Array(char.length).fill(0).map((_,i)=>char.codePointAt(i)).slice(pos||0, end)
//some code point values stop iterator; use length instead
var escapeSequence = (codes, pos, end) => codePoints(codes, pos,end).map(p=>`\\u{${p.toString(16)}}`).join('')

document.getElementById('btn').onclick=()=>{
  const text = document.getElementById('text').value
  const start = +document.getElementById('start').value
  const end = document.getElementById('end').value||undefined
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = escapeSequence(text,start,end)
}

console.log(
escapeSequence('1️⃣')
)
console.log(
escapeSequence(""),
)
console.log(
escapeSequence("my string ",10)
)
```

```html
<label for="text">unicode text: </label><input type="text" id="text"><br>
<label for="start">start position to retrieve from: </label><input type="number" id="start"><br>
<label for="end">end position to retrieve from: </label><input type="number" id="end"><br>
<button id="btn">get unicode escaped code points</button><br>
<div id="result"></div>
```